# Why does my custom flutter scaffold prevent the state from being refreshed?

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is the minimal version of what i'm attempting to do with my app that maintains the issue. The slider still responds to being interacted with by showing it's animation, however it does not change the value or actually move. This only seems to occur because the Scaffold has been separated out to it's own widget.

I know that changing it to a stateless widget would fix it in this case, however the version in my app requires state changes.

I've tried adding UniqueKeys up and down the widget tree with no luck, though i'll admit I don't fully understand their use in this case.

Any advice, or a point in the right direction? Should I keep playing around with keys, or am I going about this in the wrong way?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scaffold Test',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  double _value = 20.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyScaffold(
      child: Center(
        child: Slider(
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (double value) {
            setState(() {
              _value = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  MyScaffold({this.child});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyScaffoldState(child);
}

class MyScaffoldState extends State<MyScaffold> {
  Widget child;

  MyScaffoldState(this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: remove that  `MyScaffoldState(this.child);`  constructor (and `Widget child;` field as well) and simply use `widget.child` from your `MyScaffoldState` class

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I need to go back over the documentation after such an easy solution.

Comment: happy reading then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by user @pskink, removing the state constructor fixes the issue.

```dart
class MyScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  MyScaffold({this.child});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyScaffoldState();
}

class MyScaffoldState extends State<MyScaffold> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

In flutter, you should never have constructors for states.
if you need to initialize state properties, use `initState`.

Comment: and careful with parameter names.  do not user reserved keywords like child, parent, context.  you might confuse later.